# How do you count the number of words in each line of a textfile in C++?

Tags: c++, file, line, peek

Here is my code:
http://pastebin.com/RbFYCydf

Having issues with the output trying to get it to be looking like this:

Where the Sidewalk Ends by Shel Silverstein 7 There is a place where the sidewalk ends 8 And before the street begins, 5 And there the grass grows soft and white, 8 And there the sun burns crimson bright, 7 And there the moon-bird rests from his flight 8 To cool in the peppermint wind. 6 Let us leave this place where the smoke blows black 10 And the dark street winds and bends. 7 Past the pits where the asphalt flowers grow 8 We shall walk with a walk that is measured and slow, 11 And watch where the chalk-white arrows go 7 To the place where the sidewalk ends. 7 Yes we'll walk with a walk that is measured and slow, 11 And we'll go where the chalk-white arrows go, 8 For the children, they mark, and the children, they know 10 The place where the sidewalk ends. 6 
The total number of words is 134

Answer (score 1):

There's a better way than messing with `peek`:

First read an entire line using `getline`.
Put that line in an `istringstream`.
Count the words in that stream.
Repeat.

Details of implementation left as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a tricky way to do it must work very well.

```
string s = "this is simple test"; //assume that this is the line to be calculated
int i=0,ans=0;
while (s.find(' ',i+1)!=-1){
    i = s.find(' ',i+1);
    ans++;
}
cout<<++ans<<" ";
```

Comment: So the second one works for one line in the text file.  How do I do for each subsequent line.  Also am suppose to use the .peek() function.